# How to read/write wxpython textctrl input in linux platform?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I have a GUI created using wxpython where the path to a file fetched from a file dialog resides in textctrl which i named as Repofield.

```
self.Repofield=wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos=(120,25), size=(250,20))
value=self.Repofield.SetValue(dlg.GetPath())
```

Now i pass the '**value**' to a command using subprocess:

```
cmd="./flash -0 -f %s"%(value)  
proc=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
out,err=proc.communicate()
```

In windows, we do write the filepath to registry and read from it(runtime) when needed.How does it work in linux?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Registry in Linux. If you want to save file paths, I would recommend using a simple database like SQLite. You could also use Python's pickle module or just save them to a config file and use Python ConfigParser module to read and write to it.